# Non-amenable groups with arbitrarily large Tarski number?

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability

Just out of curiosity, I wonder whether there are non-amenable groups with arbitrarily large Tarski numbers. The Tarski number $\tau(G)$ of a discrete group $G$ is the smallest $n$ such that $G$ admits a paradoxical decomposition with $n$ pieces: $\exists A_1,\ldots,A_k,B_1\ldots,B_l\subset G$, $\exists g_1,\ldots,g_k,h_1\ldots,h_l\in G$ such that $k+l=n$ and $$G = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^k A_i\sqcup\bigsqcup_{j=1}^l B_j = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^k g_iA_i = \bigsqcup_{j=1}^l h_jB_j \quad\mbox{(disjoint unions)}.$$ Tarski's theorem says that $\tau(G)<\infty$ iff $G$ is non-amenable. It is known that $\tau(G)=4$ iff $G$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup. (See [a survey paper by Ceccherini-Silberstein, Grigorchuck, and de la Harpe](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~grigorch/publications/zCGH.pdf))

If $G$ is a non-amenable group such that every $m$ generated subgroup of it is amenable, then it satisfies $\tau(G)>m+2$ (because one may assume $g_1=e=h_1$ in the paradoxical decomposition). Such $G$ probably exists, but I do not know any examples even for $m=2$.

Comment: I think this is still an open problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, despite Mark's stellar answer, all the questions about Tarski numbers listed in the survey paper remain open, right?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

It is indeed an open problem, as Misha said. But here is a solution.  In *E. Golod, Some problems of Burnside type. 1968 Proc. Internat. Congr. Math. (Moscow,
1966) pp. 284-289. Izdat.* ”Mir”, Moscow, Golod announced, for every $m$ an infinite finitely generated torsion group all of whose $m$-generated subgroups are finite. A proof can be found in E*rshov, Mikhail, Golod-Shafarevich groups: a survey. Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 22 (2012), no. 5, 1230001, 68 pp (Theorem 3.3)*. The proof starts with a Golod-Shafarevich group $G$. If you assume that $G$ has property (T) (such groups exist by Ershov, see the survey), the resulting group will have property (T). Thus there exists a finitely generated infinite property (T), hence non-amenable, group with arbitrary large Tarski number.

**Correction.** Misha Ershov sent me two corrections.

1. It is easier to deduce the answer from Theorem 3.3 and Ershov's theorem that any GS group is non-amenable, it also can be found in the survey (this does follow from existence of property (T) GS group).
2. There exists a generalized GS group with property (T)
   and all m-gen. subgroups finite (for every fixed m). Thus a property (T) group with arbitrary large Tarski number also exists.

Comment: So the problem was open when you started writing the answer, and solved by the time you'd finished!?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: That seems eminently deserving of a +1!

Comment: The reason it was open was that when the problem was formulated by Ceccherini-Silberstein,  Grigorchuk, and de la Harpe,  GS groups with property (T) (or even with property ($\tau$)) were not known. In fact many people believed that such groups do not exist. Also I am not sure that they considered GS groups. After Ershov found a GS group with property (T), nobody noticed that it solves the problem - till now.

Comment: Amazing! I do not understand yet the proofs in Ershov, so I apologize for the following mechanical question: in Theorem 12.1 the quantity $1-H_t+H_R(t)$ is negative for $t=2/d$ while in the proof of 3.3 it starts with a group with $t$ between $1/d$ and $1/(d-1)$? Is that ok?(t= tau)

Comment: @Dan: I do not think it is a problem, you can always make $t$ smaller by adding relations (and preserving (T)).

Comment: @Mark: Great. It would be very nice if you could write some more details (if you have time, of course), this fact is a rather big improvement in the Von Neumann-Day question...

Comment: This is great, indeed. I never imagined it could be solved so quickly!

Comment: @DanSălăjan: See MR3391070 Ershov, Mikhail; Golan, Gili; Sapir, Mark The Tarski numbers of groups. Adv. Math. 284 (2015), 21–53.

Comment: Clickable link:  [Ershov, Golan, and Sapir - The Tarski numbers of groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870815002480) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3391070)).