# What is the relation between the Tarski number and growth of a group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability

When I was studying the structure of the Grigorchuk group, a question came to my mind and I just had the following information:

We know that every finitely generated group of subexponential growth is amenable so its Tarski number is infinity. Also if a group $G$ contains free group on two generators then we know from Jonsson-Dekker theorm that its Tarski number is 4. And from another theorem we can conclude that $G$ has exponential growth.

But I couldn't understand that, is there any relation between the Tarski number of a group and its growth, or not?

If I want to say what I mean, Let a group $G$ have Tarski number $k$, Is the growth function $\gamma_G (n)$ dependent to $k$ or not? Also if the growth function $\gamma_G (n)=\lambda$, is the Tarski number $\tau (G)$ dependent on $\lambda$ or not?

Answer (score 3):

All exponential growth rates are equivalent but there or groups which have infinite Tarski number (amenable). Any infinite, finitely generated, and non-nilpotent solvable groups is amenable and has exponential growth.

It is also known that there are groups with arbitrarily large Tarski number, initially proved by Mark Sapir in this [Math Overflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/137715/35370).

---

Here is an example if you want to look at "optimal", for some interpretation of optimal, growth functions.

It is not hard to see that $(2n-1)^k$ bounds $F_n$'s $k$-balls volume from below when taking the standard generating set, but $ a c^k$, for $c>2n-1$, will eventually be larger than $k$-balls. You can see a short proof in Pierre de la Harpe's paper [*Uniform growth in groups of exponential growth*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021273024728) example 2.1 that there is not a generating sets which will give you a smaller "optimal base". As you mention, $F_n$ has Tarski number 4 but they have "different growth rates" as you vary $n$ (without the standard equivalent relation).